# Trying to understand significant loss caused by OpenCV's inverse DFT

Tags: image-processing, dft

I'm quite a novice on computing Discrete Fourier Transforms with OpenCV, and I've been attempting to compute the DFT, and computing the inverse of the DFT using the latter as the input.

Judging from my attached images, from a DSP perspective, is my mapping or normalization wrong?

Here's the relevant part of code which amplifies smaller values, and normalizes them to pixel values:

```
int m = getOptimalDFTSize(img_mat.rows);
int n = getOptimalDFTSize(img_mat.cols);
cv::Mat padded;
cv::copyMakeBorder(img_mat, padded, 
    0, m - img_mat.rows, 0, 
    n - img_mat.cols, 
    cv::BORDER_CONSTANT,
    cv::Scalar::all(0));
vector<Mat> padded_channels;
split(img_mat, padded_channels);
for (int i = 0; i < padded_channels.size(); i++) {
    padded_channels[i].convertTo(padded_channels[i], CV_32FC1);
    if (g_state.processing_mode == GAFTIMAGE_PROCESSING_MODE::FT_FORWARD) {
        dft(padded_channels[i], padded_channels[i], DftFlags::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
    }
    else {
        dft(padded_channels[i], padded_channels[i],
            cv::DftFlags::DFT_INVERSE | cv::DftFlags::DFT_REAL_OUTPUT);
    }
    //normalize(padded_channels[i], padded_channels[i], 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    padded_channels[i] += Scalar::all(1);
    log(padded_channels[i], padded_channels[i]);
    normalize(padded_channels[i], padded_channels[i], 0, 1, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    padded_channels[i].convertTo(padded_channels[i], CV_8U, 255);
}
Mat final_image;
merge(padded_channels, final_image);
```

Here's the original image, along with the computed DFT and inverse DFT below:
[image: Original photo]
[image: DFT of original photo]
[image: Inverse DFT of DFT Image]

Answer (score 1):

I suggest condensing down to a smaller example. For instance doing only a single color channel, or even a hard-coded minimal test image pattern.

To my eyes your output looks like the DC-coefficient was omitted, and all color channels merged to one.